# Query - display zero where null in one column and select sum of two columns where not null in next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display a zero where "Silo Wt" is null, and display the sum of the two values in the Total column even if "Silo Wt" is null.. may not require any changes if I can get a zero in the Silo column

```
SELECT DISTINCT (coffee_type) AS "Coffee_Type",
    (SELECT ItemName
     FROM [T01_Item_Name_TBL]
     WHERE Item = B.Coffee_Type) AS "Description",
    (SELECT COUNT(Green_Inventory_ID)
     FROM [Green_Inventory] AS A
     WHERE A.Coffee_Type = B.Coffee_Type
       AND current_Quantity > 0) AS "Current Units",
    SUM((Unit_Weight) * (Current_Quantity)) AS "Green Inv Wt",
    (SELECT SUM(TGWeight)
     FROM [P04_Green_STotal_TBL] AS C
     WHERE TGItem = Coffee_type) AS "Silo Wt",
    (SUM((Unit_Weight) * (Current_Quantity)) + 
      (SELECT SUM(TGWeight)
       FROM [P04_Green_STotal_TBL] AS C
       WHERE TGItem = Coffee_type)) AS Total
FROM 
    [Green_Inventory] AS B
WHERE 
    Pallet_Status = 0
GROUP BY 
    Coffee_Type
```

[SS of query results now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEqs.png)

Comment: You could easily just wrap that column with `ISNULL`.

Comment: Also there is coalesce( sum( ... ) ,0)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT (coffee_type)` has no logical effect - your query is grouping by that column so you can only get one column per coffee_type value.

Comment: I wrapped the last two columns with isnull and that worked great!! thank you so much!!

Comment: Since you're using the same nested query twice, consider an `APPLY` operation instead to make this more efficient.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ - used with SELECT to return distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT coffee_type AS...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap them in `ISNULL`.

However, your query could do with some serious cleanup and simplification:

- `DISTINCT` makes no sense as you are grouping by that column anyway.
- Two of the subqueries can be combined using `OUTER APPLY`, although this requires moving the grouped `Green_Inventory` into a derived table.
- Another subquery, the self-join on `Green_Inventory`, can be transformed into conditional aggregation.

  - Not sure whether I've got the logic right, as the subquery did not have a filter on `Pallet_Status`, but it looks like you would also need to move that condition into conditional aggregation for the `SUM`, and use a `HAVING`. It depends exactly on your requirements.
- Don't use quoted table or column names unless you have to.
- Use *meaningful* table aliases, rather than `A` `B` `C`.
- Specify table names when referencing columns, *especially* when using subqueries, or you might get unintended results.

```sql
SELECT
    gi.Coffee_Type,
    (SELECT ItemName
     FROM T01_Item_Name_TBL AS n
     WHERE n.Item = gi.coffee_Type
    ) AS Description,
    ISNULL(gst.TGWeight, 0) AS SiloWt,
    ISNULL(gi.GreenInvWt, 0) + ISNULL(gst.TGWeight, 0) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT
        gi.Coffee_Type,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN gi.current_Quantity > 0 THEN 1 END) AS CurrentUnits,
        SUM(CASE WHEN gi.Pallet_Status = 0 THEN gi.Unit_Weight * gi.Current_Quantity END) AS GreenInvWt
    FROM
        Green_Inventory AS gi
    GROUP BY 
        gi.Coffee_Type
    HAVING
        SUM(CASE WHEN gi.Pallet_Status = 0 THEN gi.Unit_Weight * gi.Current_Quantity END) > 0
) AS gi
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(gst.TGWeight) AS TGWeight
    FROM P04_Green_STotal_TBL AS gst
    WHERE gst.TGItem = gi.Coffee_Type
) AS gst;
```

Comment: I wrapped those columns with isnull and that worked great. Also, very helpful tips - thank you everyone!